# Authors who think Culture is power?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, politics, philosophy-of-culture

The USA is leading country in military expenditure in the world. To match what the USA spends you have to add up the budget of the next 11 countries on the list combined. [ref here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_military_expenditures)

The USA is not just the most militaristic nation on earth but also the first world cultural superpower. The whole world is flooded American films, music, news, fashion, architecture, foods, etc. Even American English is the international language nowadays. In most mainstream literature and art this country is generally portrayed as the hero country of the world givers of freedom and capitalistic prosperity. It's rare to find cases in which the Americans are portrayed as villains not even in non-American films.

In history American culture (mainly Hollywood) has tried to offer an unrealistic vision of the world through art and propaganda which antagonises those considered enemies or apathetic to their Anglo-capitalistic agenda whose distortion of reality still remains up until today. ex. (Native Indians, African slavery, Socialism, Communism, Spanish-American war, The Japanese during WWII, the Vietnam war, The Russians, The Iraqis, The Iranians, etc.)

The relationship between culture and military power is nothing new. The Romans took a great deal of culture from the Greeks and the Roman Empire influenced culturally not just their colonies but neighbouring areas.

Are there any books, films authors etc who ponder on how culture is power and vice-versa?

[image: Civilization strategy game you can a achieve a cultural victory]

- *Sid Meier's Civilization® is an strategy game about world domination. In this game you can also achieve a cultural victory*

Comment: This is not a site for posting political manifestos. That power can be exercised through cultural manipulation is a platitude repeated from Marx to postmodernists.

Comment: @Conifold Is this philosophy or anglo-philosophy? (the site where all non-usa frienldy questions are closed)

Comment: This is a site where such posts are closed even if instead of  "USA" you had "France" or "China" everywhere. We just do not want to host political discussions here, even aside from be nice policy. And the text of your post is not really connected to the title question (which could be on-topic).

Comment: @Conifold This is not a political question but a philosophical one. I'm so sorry that the USA happens to be the number 1 in war and culture.

Comment: You can take a look at histories of colonization, hellenizing  programs in territories 
taken by Alexander the Great, even the Bible... Don't think the question is off-topic though, broad maybe.

Comment: @Conifold I read that as the US is just a current example of what OP is interested in. But then again if OP is looking for the pure abstraction of cultural power dynamics, a succinct answer may not be forthcoming.

Comment: @christo183 Colonization implies invading a country by force. Culture without colonisation is more subtle because it implies creating an affinity, an admiration which ultimate affects people's judgement. Ex. Europeans don't see the USA in the same way as they see North Korea or Iran.

Comment: Colonization was a much more complex and variable process than an just invasion.  But the angle I was suggesting is in the _maintenance_ of power: France for instance had, at a time, little kids in school in Africa pledge allegiance to their "motherland" France, in French, before they knew where France was or could even actually speak French. Many African countries still have European languages as the dominant form of communication. Even though they may have  violently rebelled against their colonizers, they still owe a cultural debt. When they need advice, who do they turn to...

Comment: See American Empire Project. We are probably overstretched. The average American is either too stupid, or too overworked, or both, to study the national budget.  Even if a smart citizen had the time, what chance does he have against our lobbying industry?  None, really.

Comment: @Gordon "They who have put out the people's eyes reproach them of their blindness." John Milton. Never mind because the question is closed as expected by these "philosophers"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

America's Danger of Imperial Overstretch Bloomberg News.  https://www.bloomberg.com/opinion/articles/2016-07-13/america-s-in-danger-of-imperial-overstretch

Books by the American  historian Chalmers Johnson. http://americanempireproject.com/authors/chalmers-johnson/

Answer (score 1):

The connection between culture and power is seems to have been taken for granted in the ancient world(s): Plato, Aristotle and Confucius all wrote extensively on the importance and the influence of culture (considered broadly) in the political realm.

Comment: Could you point out some references?